# Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository': Invocation of init method failed;

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, cucumber-jvm

I'm having problem in time to get the Spring context to run my tests with cucumber

I'm just climbing beans needed for the test, not all of the spring context.

Strange thing is that my entity has the Login ID property to Long

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration         
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class ConfigApplicationTests {

    }

@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigApplicationTests.class)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public class UserStepdefs {

private User user;
private static Validator validator;
private String retorno;
private Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations;


@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@Before
public static void setUp(){
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    validator = factory.getValidator();
}



@Dado("^que um usuario tenha \"([^\"]*)\" e \"([^\"]*)\" e \"([^\"]*)\" e \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void queUmUsuarioTenhaNomeSobrenomeEmailSenha(String nome, String sobrenome, String email, String senha) throws Throwable {
    Login login = new Login(email,senha);
    user = new User(nome,sobrenome,login);

}

@Quando("^eu clicar em Salvar$")
public void euClicarEmSalvar() throws Throwable {
   String message =  validateModel();
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(message)){
        userService.save(user);
        retorno = String.valueOf(HttpStatus.CREATED.value());
    }else{
        retorno = message;
    }

}


@Entao("^eu recebo \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void euRecebo(String retorno) throws Throwable {
    Assert.assertEquals(this.retorno,retorno);

}


private String validateModel() {
    String message = "";
    constraintViolations = (HashSet<ConstraintViolation<User>>) validator.validate(user);

    if(constraintViolations.iterator().hasNext()){
        message = constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage();
    }

    return message;
}


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(glue = "com.br.oor.step",
            features = "classpath:feature/User.feature",
    format = "json:target/cucumber.json",
            strict = true,
    tags = { "~@Ignore" })
public class UserServiceTest {

}

public interface LoginRepository extends JpaRepository<Login,Long> {

Optional<Login> emailEquals(String email);

/*@Query(value = "select l FROM login l where l.id = ?1 and l.email =  ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)*/
Optional<Login> idNotEqualsAndEmailEquals(Long id ,String email);
}
```

LOGERROR

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.CucumberTestContextManager.getContext(SpringFactory.java:215)
at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.CucumberTestContextManager.<init>(SpringFactory.java:207)
at cucumber.runtime.java.spring.SpringFactory.start(SpringFactory.java:102)
at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.buildWorld(JavaBackend.java:123)
at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.buildBackendWorlds(Runtime.java:140)
at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:38)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property not found for type Long! Traversed path: Login.id.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframewor
```

Answer (score 0):

The original problem is: `No property not found for type Long! Traversed path: Login.id`.
It looks like your `Login` entity `id` field is not a `Long` type.

Spring Data Jpa has a very good API. You can replace your `@Query` with finder:

```
Optional<Login> findOneByIdAndEmail(Long id ,String email);
```